# Compare the last overall coverage to the current overall coverage precentage in GitLab

Tags: compare, gitlab-ci, code-coverage, pipeline, failover

I am looking for a way to use the overall coverage percentage used and shown in the history of coverage in GitLab and compare in a way so the pipeline will fail if the difference between the current overall coverage and the last one is more than X, where X can be configurable.

important to note I am using gcovr as a tool to produce the coverage report during the pipeline run, and it is working fine and as stated before I need a way to compare the last and make the pipeline fail accordingly, I do not know how GitLab saves this information but I do know I can use artifacts/caches in the gitlab-ci.yml to achieve this but with the exception of having expiration for the artifacts which I do not want (cause if there is expiration and someone will trigger code coverage after the expiration it wont work)  and also I do not want save every time or for ever all the coverage results until now just the last one.

thanks in advance.

I tried to look for explanation on internet for doing that but I could not find information on how GitLab saves this information which is shown all the time on the history page in the graph of the coverage.